# Time methods in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I see in http://api.rubyonrails.org/ rails `3.2.12` that the class `Time` has a set of methods like:

```
beginning_of_day,
beginning_of_hour,
beginning_of_month,
beginning_of_quarter,
beginning_of_week,
beginning_of_year
```

When I try something like `t = Time.beginning_of_hour` in the rails console, I get an undefined method error.

How can I experiment with these methods?

Comment: `Time.now.beginning_of_day`

Comment: @Unixmonkey can I set the Time.now.beginning_of_day at some particular time? e.g. Time.now.beginning_of_day(9).

Comment: Do you mean like `9.days.ago.beginning_of_day` ?

Comment: @Unixmonkey, no, I'm looking to set a range of business hours and I want to set two variables 'start' and 'end'. like start_time(9am) end_time(16pn).

Comment: `Time.now + 9.hours`? Also, tip for dealing with Timezones: `Time.zone.now`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24341/discussion-between-evanx-and-unixmonkey)

Answer (score 2):

It is `Date.today`. There is `Time.now` if you want to use that.